# Detecting multiple array coordinates in canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

Hello fellow programmers,

Today I have a question that's related to one of my projects I'm making kinda like Tower Defense using canvas. However, I stuck on trying to detect multiple circles in one coordinate. Here's my example:

```
for (var a = 0; a < buildArcherX.length; a++) {
    for (var a = 0; a < buildArcherY.length; a++) {
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(buildArcherX[a] - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(buildArcherY[a] - this.y, 2)) <= arch.radius + 7) {
            this.attackedByArcher = true;
        } else {
            this.attackedByArcher = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in this example, I'm using arrays to put my coordinates in for my "Defenses". The for statements runs through all the "defense" coordinates in the arrays. The if statement in the code calculates if any of the defense coordinates are within "this" coordinates. This returns a boolean if any of the defenses are in range.

However I got to this point, and then got stuck on this problem: What happens if multiple defenses are in range? Then "this" would need to take more damage. So I'm just wondering if I can show the **number** of defenses in range.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps put a counter in the for-loops instead of just true/false? `var counter=0; for ... for ... if(...){counter++}` and `return(counter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an integer to store the value of how many defenses are in range and increment it whenever a defense has been found in range.

Also, you must use 2 different variables when nesting loops.

```
this.defensesInRange = 0;
for (var x = 0; x < buildArcherX.length; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < buildArcherY.length; y++) {
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(buildArcherX[x] - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(buildArcherY[y] - this.y, 2)) <= arch.radius + 7) {
            this.defensesInRange += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if its running under a loop? Then the number will increase under the loop a bajillion times.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you have a 3rd loop?

Comment: I have a setInterval function which loops.

Comment: The variable, as I've assigned outside the 2 loops, will reset every time this code block is executed.

Comment: It worked, sorta, because somehow "this" didn't take any damage until the right-most defense was in range.

Comment: Well, this code snippet looks alright to me. Maybe there is a problem somewhere else..